# firestore firebase not adding the information I send to it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, frontend

So I am creating a react app to manage routines, and I set up the database with firestore. Now, everything works fine when I try to retrieve data from the database, but when I want to send it data, it never saves it unless the console is open, and even then it functions sometimes.

this is the code I use to add an item:

```
const addNewItem = async(titleValue,descriptionValue, repetitionValue) =>{
   try {
     await addDoc(routineCollectionRef,{
     title:titleValue,
     description:descriptionValue,
     repetition:repetitionValue
   })
   .then(console.log('thing done'))
   } catch (error) {
     console.error(error)
   }
}
```

I guess it's worth specifying that I start the server and add the data in two different files, but by importing the reference key from the first to the second everything should work fine I guess.

Comment: Can you add what error has printed in console?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: what is the error you are getting? can you share the error?